Windows task scheduler to execute python script - 0x1 error
I have a python script on a server. It places data from MS SQL Server into a df, then creates a CSV file to a location on the server, and then uploads the CSV file to an FTP site. It checks if there is already a file in that location before creating the CSV, and deletes it if there is.
I want Windows Task Scheduler to do this. I have a service account that I want to set the task up with, but if I use that account, the task produces 0x1. If I use my own account, the task executes fine, suggesting there is a permission problem with the service account.
I have made sure the service account has full permissions in the location where the CSV would be deleted from, and created to. I have also made sure the account has permissions in the database that the script selects data from. What else can I check?

If you use some pip modules, these might be installed on your local user making them unavailable for the service account

Try setting up the script to run from a location accessible to all users, including its virtual environment. You can have the Task Scheduler execute a script (bat / ps1) that activates the environment and runs the script, so that everything is available to the service account. If you need to separate it off, consider setting the service account to allow desktop login, set up the script on the service account, sign out again and remove that right - the version configured for the service account should only be accessible to the service account and admins.

Probably you're hitting some permissions issue. Use a "Run as user" Command Prompt to execute the script to make sure that it actually works and can access everything using that particular account. If it works doing that but still fails as a Windows Scheduled Task... then likely it is not loading the user account's Profile correctly (including registry hives which contain settings, environment variables, etc.).
